# How does a body when dropped in a fluid take infinite time to attain terminal velocity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I know that the velocity is asymptotic but how is that i would like to know thanks !

Comment: What does "asymptotic" mean?

Comment: From what i know asymptotic function is when the variable tends to infinity as the expression approaches a value

Comment: You're quite wrong. Asymptotic means that the function tends to ANY value, but it never gets to reach that. If a growth is asymptothic, the slope tends to a concrete value but it never gets to that value. Look for the meaning of "asymptote".

Comment: But how is the terminal velocity asymptotic?

Comment: It only theoretically takes infinite time, of course; no experiment has yet lasted that long.

Answer (score 1):

You can say that on your body act two forces: weigth $ F_1 = m g$  and drag 
$F_2 = -k v$. They point in opposite directions, hence the minus.

Now your differential equation for velocity is

$$
m \frac{dv}{dt} = mg - k v,
$$ 
which can be integrated as  (let's say $v(0) = 0$)
$$
v(t) = \frac{mg}{k}(1 - e^{-\frac{k}{m}t})
$$

You can check that velocity is increasing (the derivative is positive), and you have that 
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} v(t) = \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\frac{mg}{k}(1 - e^{-\frac{k}{m}t}) = \frac{mg}{k}(1 - e^{-\infty})  = \frac{mg}{k}.
$$
Hence, velocity is increasing and reaches its maximum at infinity (i.e. asymptotically).

A mathematician would say that your function 
$$
v(t) = \frac{mg}{k}(1 - e^{-\frac{k}{m}t})
$$
has an horizontal asymptote $v = \frac{mg}{k}$ for $t\rightarrow \infty$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much but why have we not taken buoyant force into account?

Answer (score 0):

If you drop a body in a fluid with high viscosity you get a Stokes drag force $$F_{drag}=-k v$$ proportional and opposite to the velocity of the body. Thus you have Newtons law $$m\dot v=mg-kv$$ For an initial velocity zero at $t=0$ this has the solution $$v(t)=\frac {m g}{k}[1-exp (-\frac {k t}{m})]$$ The end velocity is $$v_{\infty}=\frac {m g}{k}$$ for $t \to \infty$ as the exponential term goes to zero. For any practical purpose, this exponentially decreasing term is zero when the time is a much larger than $m/k$. Only *mathematically* $v_{\infty}$ is never reached at a finite time.

A similar end velocity is reached by parachuters in air. There the drag force is proportional to $v^2$.